# Use of "and" and "or" to refer to values for comparison

Tags: comparisons

I've gotten into a disagreement with a colleague.  My original sentence was "Determine the maximum value of Boys *and* Girls."  My colleague thought that the sentence should read "Determine the maximum value of Boys *or* Girls."

I can't find any material on this and I gather that it is quite possible that both are correct.

My question is related to the use of "and" or "or" in the sentence, which one is correct?  An additional posting my me has provided additional details.

Comment: _That_ is likely a mistake; it would only work if there were a specific example of a "maximum value of Boys and Girls" (out of several examples) that had previously come up in the conversation. In that case, it would be a demonstrative _that_ and would mean _Determine that maximum value (-- the one we were discussing previously)_. But that's unlikely, whereas _the_ is normal.

Comment: Welcome, Patrick! No need to write "thanks" or sign your name - [your username shows up at the bottom of each post](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).

Comment: What is your sentence meant to mean: (1) Combined total of boys plus girls; (2) Total number of boys and (separately) total number of girls; (3) Whether there are more boys than girls or vice versa; (4) Total number of boys *OR* total number of girls, whichever you choose. Your question is impossible to answer since it is not clear what value you are wanting.

Comment: Trevor's right: as posed, it's ambiguous. "Value of" and "number of" have diffferent meanings. Temperature, for example, has a value, not a number ("90 degrees" is a value expressed as a number); the number of eggs in a dozen is 12. Also, why are "Boys" and "Girls" capitalized? Only proper nouns (names of places &c) are capitalized.

Comment: I was trying to be brief.  The sentence was part of a verbal explanation to my customer as to the logic the system uses to determine the value it uses to calculate an order quanityt.  The capitalization, though not correct as you say, was used by me to emphasize this a a variable.  In my company, the standard is to use title caps for these things and I let that slip into this post.

The variables are Temp-OP and OP which have previously been defined.  The sentence is "Then, the system takes the maximum of Temp-OP and OP to determine the order quantity."

Answer (score 1):

"or" is not the solution. You need to add an "of" before "Girls".

Comment: Hi Trevor, I see that my question is still on hold.  I think I've added the additional information to make the question clearer.  Is it possible that you can remove it from hold?